# regular expression not validating 4 value types of numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate a value and that value cannot have a zero and then a number in front of it in my expression, the expression I have currently selects all the data types of values including the first one which is not what I want can someone help me please.

```
05lb incorrect
0.2lb correct
1.2lb correct
2lb correct

/(0?[0-9]|\d+)(?:\.\d\lb|\lb)/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide your condition (*value cannot have a zero and then a number in front*) on regex by using a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$
```

`^(?!0\d)` asserts that the there isn't a  `0` and a digit present at the start.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sV8yT8/1)

```
> /^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$/.test('05lb')
false
> /^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$/.test('0.2lb')
true
> /^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$/.test('1.2lb')
true
> /^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?lb$/.test('2lb')
true
```

Comment: I also need to make sure I don't have 0lb as well do you know how to add that into the expression

Answer (score 1):

some points are not completely clear (i.e.: always lb at the end? max 1 digit after point? numbers as 1.lb are allowed?), but you can try this:

```
/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d)?lb$/
```